# Deploy less files

Tags: magento-2.1, less-css

I'm new in Magento 2 and I learning it now. I am trying to customize email templates by editing default **/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/web/css/email-inline.less** file in my theme, but I not understand one thing.

When I commented all lines in this file (and deleted @magento_import), I clear cache and deploy static files for my theme:

```
grunt clean:Theme && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

After this command invoked successfully, I checked files **email-inline.less** and **email-inline.css** in **/pub/static/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Locale/css/** directory.

File **email-inline.less** same as in my theme, but **email-inline.css** for some reason is not empty.

Why does it happen?

Comment: have you tried *grunt less:your_theme* ?

Comment: and are you sure this directory is correct pub/static/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Locale/css ?

Comment: Yes, of course, this right

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile one time all themes:

```
grunt clean && grunt exec && grunt less
```

Or just on your theme `grunt clean:mytheme && grunt exec:mytheme && grunt less:mytheme`,

`grunt:exec` copies in var/view_preprocessed files from Magento 2 project (vendor, app/, lib, ..)

Comment: grunt less do same setup:static-content:deploy. I not right?

Comment: Try to compile everything to all themes. I had fixed a similar issue with it. grunt:exec is the most important command. I find running grunt commands more stable.

Comment: I configured grunt and this work great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put all your email styles in

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/css/source/_email.less

now you need to deploy changes. You can do this via

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

or use *grunt*

```
grunt less:your_theme
```

if you get error about missing files you need to run

```
grunt exec:your_theme
```

don't forget **your_theme** should be under

> dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js

Here is more information
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html

**NOTICE**. if you still do not see changes it could be just cache issue. To prevent this you need re-deploy with Sign enabled.
http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/static-file-signature.html

Comment: This is clear, but I not understand why email-inline.css compiled with a empty email-inline.less

Comment: Are you sure you have no compilation errors? Magento use both files email.less and email-inline.less in Less Processor to collect styles from modules and themes including inherited

Comment: not sure where is the issue ... here is quick solution... 
1. enable developer mode
2. remove email files in pub/static/frontend/...../css/email.css and email-inline.css
3. then just call both files in browser directly. Magento should compile your file on the fly.

Comment: No, compile on the fly not works. But I found reason of issue: less files cached in /var/view_preprocessed directory and if run grunt clean:var before setup:static-content:deploy - is problem not repeat. Thank you!